# Firebase runTransactionBlock returns maxretry error after reestablishing connection

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, offline

```
ref.runTransactionBlock({ (currentData) -> FIRTransactionResult in
     // change data here
     return FIRTransactionResult.successWithValue(currentData)
     }, andCompletionBlock: { (error, committed, snapshot) in
        if let error = error {
           print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
})
```

This is an example of the firebase transaction I am using. Steps to reproduce my problem:

1. put your phone on airplane mode
2. run transaction
3. keep phone offline for a while
4. return wifi on

Expected:

- transaction will run based on the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/offline-capabilities#section-handling-transactions-offline)

  > Any transactions that are performed while the app is offline, are queued. Once the app regains network connectivity, the transactions are sent to the Realtime Database server.

Result:

- console keep printing :
  __nw_connection_get_connected_socket_block_invoke x Connection has no connected handler
- finally prints error maxretry

Comment: While there is no connection, the transactions should be retrying.  After it reconnects, it will try and if needed retry. But it looks like you have significant contention on the location and the client runs out of retries before it can get its own value written. If you enable debug logging (see https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/FIRDatabase#setloggingenabled), the logging will show the exact interactions/wire traffic. That will help in troubleshooting.